# razor list<MyObject> element was not closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a cshtml template and I'm using Razor to populate it. I'm passing an object that has several sub-lists inside it and I need to get the values from one of the items in one the sub-lists to use in the body of the text. So in the opening tag I have this:

```
@{ 
   var myId = @Model.myId;
   List<MyObject> newObj = @Model.MyList.Where(l => l.Id == myId).ToList();
 }
```

But when I try to execute the template, it throws an error that '<'MyObject'>' was not closed, that all elements must have a matching self-closing tag or end tag. I understand that it seems to be reading this as an html tag, but why since its clearly inside the programming markup? Can I not call a list object in razor? If so, how do I get to this specific sub-list of items?

I've checked the rest of the page and the html has all its closing marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to fix your code you would have to do the following:

```
@{ 
   var myId = Model.myId;
   List<MyObject> newObj = Model.MyList.Where(l => l.Id == myId).ToList();
 }
```

Which simply removes the @ in front of the Model's.

However I feel that a better solution to your problem is to try and keep the logic code in your controller rather than your view.

As an example, if you are using a Partial View.

In your view you could call an action and pass in your model like this:

```
@Html.Action("MyAction", Model)
```

This would call a controller action that would do your select i.e.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
     var newList = model.MyList.Where(l => l.Id == myId).ToList();
     return PartialView("_MyPartial", newList);
}
```

Then use the `@model` attribute within your partial i.e.

```
@model List<MyObject>
```

Comment: This did resolve my issue, but would you mind helping me understand the benefit to keeping the code in the controller? Would this also apply to other data calls I might wish to make?

Comment: Sure, no problem. It's personal preference really but I find that it is better practice to try and keep logic out of my views and in my controllers (or services under them). Keeping the logic in your views can become very cluttered and not very re-usable.

Comment: I do have some repeat code so I can see where that would definitely help me, thanks.